# Filter a RDD in java to split into 2 new RDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

I'm trying to filter my RDD so I can create 2 new RDDs

My RDD contains numbers and 1 string. This String has 2 possible values - `Yes` and `No`, is how i want to filter my RDD.

I know in python I can do this:

```
rdd.filter(rdd.contains(_))
```

but I want to do this in Java, is this possible ?

Comment: In most cases, if you want two seperate RDDs, you have to write two seperate transfromations. Also, I don't think you can do `rdd.filter(rdd.contains(_))`

Comment: Yes I know ill need 2 separate transformations, I'm not an expert in python but i know its something similar to that